# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 E-mail Router SchedulingPeriod in milliseconds?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am attempting to speed up sent e-mail in CRM 2011 by editing the Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.xml file. I am modifying the SchedulingPeriod element and I am not sure if the interval setting is in seconds or milliseconds.

The CRM 4.0 documentation from Microsoft states “all time intervals in the configuration file are specified in milliseconds.” http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc906241.aspx

The Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Unleashed Book states “The outgoing e-mails are processed asynchronously, and the default polling is scheduled for every 1,000 seconds (about 15 minutes), so you must wait that time before the e-mails are actually sent.”

**Tip:** To increase the speed at which outgoing e-mails are sent, you can edit the configuration file Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.xml (which is usually located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft CRM Email\Service) and find the SchedulingPeriod element. We recommend changing its default value to 10 seconds.

**Question 1:** In CRM 2011, is the SchedulingPeriod specified in milliseconds or seconds?

**Question 2:** In CRM 2011, is the default SchedulingPeriod (1,000) = 1 second or 15 minutes?

The Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Unleashed book mentions speeding up outgoing e-mails by changing the default value to 10 seconds.
**Question 3:** In CRM 2011, will changing the SchedulingPeriod to (10) = 10 seconds or 10 milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is in seconds, 1000 seconds == 16 minutes 35 seconds, there should also be a setting for number of threads just above this in the file that you can increase to improve performance.

Like everything CRM though test it first as your setup might behave differently to mine, speeding this up might just move your bottleneck elsewhere - usually the UI if you havent put it on another server.  also concider if you are using Virtual Servers and they are on the same physical hardware making one work more can slow the others if they aren't balenced correctly.

Comment: Do you know if all the timer interval settings, in Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.xml, are specified in seconds for CRM 2011?